# Fetch Process Name With runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: and OSXFuse

Tags: objective-c, macos, fuse, nsrunningapplication, osxfuse

I am using OSXFuse and get the processID of the application that wants to read a file in the FUSE Filesystem on Mac. Using the OSXFuse `[GMUserFileSystem currentContext]`, we fetch the process ID and now I would like to get the application name from this process ID. Most of the time, Finder is the calling process and its running under current logged in User privileges. I am trying to pass the process ID to `runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:` to fetch the process details including its name. However `runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:` returns nil. I have ensured the process ID is valid and also under user privileges. What might be wrong?

I am aware there are other ways like using some raw C based api's for fetching the process name, but I would like to fetch it using `runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:` as it can give more useful information

Comment: I have exact the same behavior. 

NSRunningApplication *appFromPid = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:pid];

NSString *bundleId = appFromPid.bundleIdentifier;

I believe not every app has bundle id.

Comment: "I am aware there are other ways like using some raw C based api's for fetching the process name"
Can you give me clue? Which Api i can use?

Comment: Here is the C style code to fetch the process path  `GetProcessPathForID(int processID){
    
    pid_t pid;
    int result;
    char pathbuf[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
    pid = (pid_t)processID;
    
    result = proc_pidpath (pid, pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf));
    NSString *processPath = @"";
    if ( result > 0 ) {
        processPath = [NSString stringWithCString:pathbuf encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
    
    return processPath.UTF8String;
}`

Comment: Thanks! I need this because system archiver have bundle id com.apple.finder the same as finder. I uses bundle id for filtering app access